# Adding to front of List throws?

Tags: java, list

Trying to use the following to add to the front of a List but throws on the add.  The doc says it's supposed to shift.  What is the fix or workaround?

```
List<String> whatever = Arrays.asList("Blah1", "Blah2");
whatever.add(0, "BlahAll"); // <- Throws
```

Comment: It doesn't just "throw", it throws a particular exception. Is it perhaps `UnsupportedOperationException`, since `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `List` generated by `Arrays.asList()` is not an `ArrayList` but another list that doesn't suport that operation (contract for `List` says `add()` is optional)

As a workaround you could do this:

```
List<String> whatever = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Blah1", "Blah2"));
whatever.add(0, "BlahAll");
```

Comment: This worked great! new ArrayList<String>(Array.asList("Blah1", "Blah2")); thx

Answer (score 5):

You can't add element to a list created using `Arrays.asList()`. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) explains:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Comment: @chrylis:  Care to elaborate?  The documentation seems to back this answer up....

Comment: @DrewHall I already changed my answer. The comment was for a previous version of my answer. chryslis should wait a while before commenting and voting down…

Comment: @DrewHall actually chrylis was right at the time he posted his comment, after that this answer was edited

Comment: correct explanation, appreciate the documentation link, upvote

Comment: thanks guys...great info...I just find it odd that the container isn't smart enough to box/unbox from an array to the left type.  upvote

Comment: @JaJ: I'm not an expert at Java implementations, but I'd *guess* that Arrays.asList() doesn't actually move any data around.  It sets things up so that you can use the List methods on the array (except for those that would require changing the array).  Using `new ArrayList(...)` needs to make a copy of some stuff (probably just a copy of the references to the elements) and create a new data structure, which takes some processing time, which is needed in your example but would be wasted in a different program that didn't need add() or insert().

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size array. If you want to be able to add additional items, you need to create another `List` object, perhaps with `whatever = new ArrayList<String>(array)`.

Answer (score 3):

What does it throw, UnsupportedOperationException?  add() on a List is documented as an "optional operation".  When you created a list by Arrays.asList(), it doesn't create any new data structures, it just uses the existing array as the basis for doing your List operations (I think).  That makes insertion impossible.

You'll need to decide on another implementation of your List, such as a LinkedList:

```
List<String> whatever = new LinkedList<String> (Arrays.asList("Blah1", "Blah2"));
```

(I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 1):

**Here you Used Arrays Instead of Array List.**

> **Read This Before You Fix Your Issue**

Major difference between Array and ArrayList in Java is that Array is a **fixed length data structure** while **ArrayList** is a variable length Collection class.

You can not change length of Array once created in Java but ArrayList re-size itself when gets full depending upon capacity and load factor.

Since **Array List** is internally backed by Array in Java, any resize operation in **ArrayList will slow down performance as it involves creating new Array and copying content from old array to new array**.

But Here you need to used ArrayList Since you need to add Data in the later stage.

```
List<String> whatever = new ArratList(Arrays.asList("Blah1", "Blah2"));
whatever.add(0, "BlahAll");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try google library,

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

List<String> whatever = Lists.newArrayList("Blah1", "Blah2");
whatever.add(0, "BlahAll");
```

Comment: it automatically infers the generics (one of the key suggestions by Effective Java) and is really well supported. it has plethora of variations of constructors and supports other collections like Set, Map too. do give it a shot.